# Add new rows in HTML table consisting of dropdown lists, radio buttons and optional textbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, foreach

I am doing a project where the user should be able to fill up their data in an HTML table which is in a form and then submit it to a database.

In the form, the table looks like this: (top part of the 1st photo)

However, when I add a new row, I do not have the dropdown list and radio options. For the Langauge Name, I want an optional textbox field if the user selects 'Others' option.
The table now looks like this: (bottom part of the 1st photo)
[HTML table before and after adding a row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djelN.jpg)

I know the php code for the table is the problem but I do not know how to rectify it.

In the database, I only receive the data of the first row but NOT the subsequent rows. There should be 2 rows of entries with the same timestamp. (2nd photo)
[Database entries of the HTML table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wde2.png)

The codes are attached below:

**Page5.blade.php** (the javascript is in the blade.php file)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">

            <title>Dynamic Table row creation and Deletion - Bootsnipp.com</title>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
            <style type="text/css">

            </style>
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.alert = function(){};
                var defaultCSS = document.getElementById('bootstrap-css');
                function changeCSS(css){
                    if(css) $('head > link').filter(':first').replaceWith('<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+ css +'" type="text/css" />'); 
                    else $('head > link').filter(':first').replaceWith(defaultCSS); 
                }
                $( document ).ready(function() {
                  var iframe_height = parseInt($('html').height()); 
                  window.parent.postMessage( iframe_height, 'https://bootsnipp.com');
                });
            </script>



        </head>
        <body>
        @extends('layout.basiclayout')

        @section('content')

        <p>page 5/7</p>


                {!! Form::open(['url' => 'page5/submit']) !!}

                    <h3 style='text-decoration: underline'>LANGUAGE PROFICIENCY - </h3>
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12 column">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
                <thead>
                  <tr >
                    <th class="text-center">#</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Langauge Name:</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Spoken Proficiency:</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Written Proficiency:</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Understanding Proficiency:</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr id='addr0'>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td><div class="form-group">
                          {{Form::select('Language_Name',array(
                          'English'=>'English',
                          'Tamil'=>'Tamil',
                          'Malay'=>'Malay',
                          'Chinese'=>'Chinese',
                          'Brumese'=>'Brumese',
                          'Filipino'=>'Filipino',
                          'Indonesian'=>'Indonesian',
                          'Japanese'=>'Japanese',
                          'Taiwanese'=>'Taiwanese',
                          'Thai'=>'Thai',
                          'Vietnamese'=>'Vietnamese',
                          'Others'=>'Others' ))}}
                        </div></td>
                  <td><div class="form-group">
                          {{Form::radio('Spoken_Proficiency','Excellent') }} Excellent <br>
                          {{Form::radio('Spoken_Proficiency','Good') }} Good <br>
                          {{Form::radio('Spoken_Proficiency','Poor') }} Poor
                        </div></td>
                        <td><div class="form-group">
                          {{Form::radio('Written_Proficiency','Excellent') }} Excellent <br>
                          {{Form::radio('Written_Proficiency','Good') }} Good <br>
                          {{Form::radio('Written_Proficiency','Poor') }} Poor
                        </div></td>
                        <td><div class="form-group">
                          {{Form::radio('Understanding_Proficiency','Excellent') }} Excellent <br>
                          {{Form::radio('Understanding_Proficiency','Good') }} Good <br>
                          {{Form::radio('Understanding_Proficiency','Poor') }} Poor
                        </div></td>
                  </tr>
                            <tr id='addr1'></tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left btn-success">Add Row</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default btn-danger">Delete Row</a>
        </div>

        <br>
        <h4><b>Computer Knowledge</b></h4>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{Form::radio('Computer_Knowledge','Excellent') }} Excellent
                            {{Form::radio('Computer_Knowledge','Good') }} Good
                            {{Form::radio('Computer_Knowledge','Poor') }} Poor
                        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">


                   $(document).ready(function(){
              var i=1;
             $("#add_row").click(function(){
              $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><input name='Language_Name[]"+"' type='text' class='form-control'</td><td><input name='Spoken_Proficiency[]"+"' type='text' class='form-control'></td><td><input  name='Written_Proficiency[]"+"' type='text' class='form-control'></td><td><input  name='Understanding_Proficiency[]"+"' type='text' class='form-control'></td>");

          $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
              i++; 
              });
          $("#delete_row").click(function(){
               if(i>1){
                     $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
                     i--;
                     }
               });

        });
           </script>
              <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                          {{Form::submit('Next Page', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
                    </div>

        {!! Form::close() !!}
        </body>
        </html>
        @endsection
```

**LanguageProficiencyController.php** (I know there is a problem with the foreach loop but I do not know how to solve it)

```
     <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\LanguageProficiency;

    class LanguageProficiencyController extends Controller
    {
            public function submit(Request $request){

            //language proficiency table
            foreach($request->get('Language_Name') as $Language_Name) {
                $LanguageProficiency = new LanguageProficiency;


            foreach($request->get('Spoken_Proficiency') as $Spoken_Proficiency) {
            foreach($request->get('Written_Proficiency') as $Written_Proficiency) {
            foreach($request->get('Understanding_Proficiency') as $Understanding_Proficiency) {

            $LanguageProficiency->Language_Name = $Language_Name;
            $LanguageProficiency->Spoken_Proficiency = $Spoken_Proficiency;
            $LanguageProficiency->Written_Proficiency = $Written_Proficiency;
            $LanguageProficiency->Understanding_Proficiency = $Understanding_Proficiency;



            $LanguageProficiency->Computer_Knowledge = $request->input('Computer_Knowledge');

            $LanguageProficiency->save();
        return redirect('http://formapplication.dev/page6');

        }}}}
      }

    }
```

**migration file.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateLanguageProficienciesTable extends Migration{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up(){
        Schema::create('language_proficiencies', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');

            //create table
            //$table-> string or integer('field name');

            $table->string('Language_Name');
            $table->string('Spoken_Proficiency');
            $table->string('Written_Proficiency');
            $table->string('Understanding_Proficiency');

            //ADD SECOND LANGUAGE/DIALECT FIELDS HERE

            $table->string('Computer_Knowledge');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down(){
        Schema::dropIfExists('language_proficiencies');
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a return value in the most inner foreach loop. Do you want to exit your method without looping? Because that's what's happening now

Comment: Then how do I change it?

Comment: While looking at your code; Why do you use loops? Are you expecting multiple entries in 'spoken_proficiences' (or the others for that matter)? Then they are not named very well. If you only need a single field from the request, you can access it with $request['<field_that_you_want_to_access>']

Comment: Yes, I'm expecting multiple entries from a single field because I'm adding rows to the html thus there will be multiple rows